# Why doesn't this remove all of the items from the <select> element?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a function that is supposed to remove all child elements from a `<select>` on the `onfocus` event. (this is soon to be followed by filling the `<select>` with values from an AJAX call) For some reason, it only removes one of the elements the first time it is called , and then proceeds to do nothing all subsequent calls. Does anyone have any clue as to why this might be happening?

JS Code:

```
function handle(e) {
  for(var i = 0; i < e.children.length - 1; i++) {
    e.removeChild(e.children[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you remove child[0], then child[1] immediately becomes child[0]. Use jQuery empty() function.

Comment: OH!!!!!!, so I should remove them in inverse order. (facepalms self)

Comment: To remove options, just set `select.options.length = 0` or `while (select.firstChild) select.removeChild(select.firstChild)` or… Oh, and it will be the same for any element with more than one child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm guessing `handle()` is your `onfocus` event handler. in which case `e` is your event object and doesn't have any `children` property

why not just use `select.innerHTML  = ""`

Comment: Wow (facepalms self again) (facepalms self again) (Sokka-Face unlocked)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is simply to remove them in inverse order, as to avoid the effects of a indexing system quite similar to the VB.NET List Class. (That is that it reorganizes itself every time a change is made.